# How to shorten binding.pry without using dollar-sign global variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, binding, pry

```
binding.pry
```

is a cool command and many people use it. But it's too much to type each time. What is the best way to add a shorthand for it, something like

```
bp
```

Please don't suggest putting a

```
$bp = binding.pry
```

into initializers but anything without the dollar sign?

Comment: Define an editor shortcut that expands `bp<tab>` (or whatever) to `binding.pry`.

Comment: This would be over-engineered. Just type it or use a shortcut.

Comment: Do you want to use the `bp` shorthand in any project that you might be working on?

Comment: @punkle - yes, per project would be perfect. i think it's just a bad design - forcing a programmer to write 11 letters each time :) i can type blindly, and yet..

Comment: @Stefan, thanks for the text editor key binding idea. used `{"keys": ["ctrl+shift+y"], "command": "insert_snippet","args": {"contents": "binding.pry"}}` for sublime (in preferences > key bindings - user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a little thought, here's the solution. It will require one more `next` to hit. But there are the other benefits - you can define it per environment, so you'll never get an error on production if you forget to delete or comment out `bp`.

Go to initializers, and create pry.rb file with these contents:

```
def bp
  unless %w(production).include? Rails.env
    binding.pry
  end
end
```

Have fun!

Comment: MRI stops on binding.pry line in pry.rb itself, which is not desired behavior (

Answer (score 2):

I just created a gem for this purpose:
[pry-alias](http://rubygems.org/gems/pry-alias)

Comment: works in rspec test, but doesn't work when I run rails app

Answer (score 0):

@valk's solution did not work for me because MRI stops on binding.pry line in pry.rb itself, here is what worked for me using a custom snippet:

To create a custom snippet, open VS Code Command Palette `Shift + Command + P` (Mac) / `Ctrl + Shift + P` (Windows/Linux), type `User Snippets`, select  `Configure User Snippets`, and select `ruby.json` as the language identifier and paste this code into it. Here is the [reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets):

```
"Shorten binding.pry": {
  "prefix": "bp",
  "body": [
    "binding.pry"
  ],
  "description": "Add binding using pry gem"
}
```